# want to make week records dynamic based on current_date

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query (for BigQuery) in which I want to count week wise records keeping my sqlcode dynamic with respect to date.
Query for daily records is as follows:

```
select o.date as order_date, count(distinct(customer_id)) as WAU  
from xyz.orders o 
where o.date = current_date() and o.refund =0 and o.parent_order_id is null and o.status=1 
group by o.date
```

`o.refund`, `o.parent_order_id` and `o.status` are filters.

Want to make same query to be dynamic for week where week is defined from Monday to Sunday. For current_date i.e 2021-09-18, week is Sept 13 - Sept 19.[Output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD5AU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery)

```
select 
  format('%t - %t', date_trunc(o.date, week(monday)), 6 + date_trunc(o.date, week(monday))) as Week, 
  count(distinct customer_id) as WAU  
from `xyz.orders` o 
where o.refund = 0 
and o.parent_order_id is null 
and o.status = 1 
group by Week
```

The output will be like in below example

[image]

In case if you need Week to be formatted exactly like it is shown in your question - try below then

```
select 
  format('%t - %t', 
    format_date('%b %d', date_trunc(o.date, week(monday))), 
    format_date('%b %d', 6 + date_trunc(o.date, week(monday)))
  ) as Week, 
  count(distinct customer_id) as WAU  
from `xyz.orders` o 
where o.refund = 0 
and o.parent_order_id is null 
and o.status = 1 
group by Week
```

OR

```
select 
  format('%t - %t', 
    cast(date_trunc(o.date, week(monday)) as string format('Mon dd')), 
    cast(6 + date_trunc(o.date, week(monday)) as string format('Mon dd'))
  ) as Week, 
  count(distinct customer_id) as WAU  
from `xyz.orders` o 
where o.refund = 0 
and o.parent_order_id is null 
and o.status = 1 
group by Week
```

both with output like

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Code working correctly.